# Performance issues with nested Views in ScrollView and header - Replacing with FlatLists

Tags: react-native, jsx, react-native-flatlist, react-native-scrollview

I'm currently working on a React Native project and facing performance issues related to using nested `Views` within a `ScrollView`, along with a header. Here's an overview of the current structure:

1. A main `ScrollView` that contains a general header and two `Views` positioned next to each other in a flex-row layout.
2. Each of the two `Views` has a flex-column layout and contains an array of topics as child elements.

```
-------------------------------------------
|                General Header           |
-------------------------------------------
|            |                            |
|   View     |        View                |
|            |                            |
|   Topics   |        Topics              |
|            |                            |
|            |                            |
|            |                            |
|            |                            |
|            |                            |
|            |                            |
|            |                            |
|            |                            |
|            |                            |
|            |                            |
|            |                            |
|            |                            |
|            |                            |
|            |                            |
|            |                            |
-------------------------------------------
```

In this representation:

- The "General Header" is a separate element at the top.
- Below the header, there are two side-by-side "Views", each containing multiple "Topics".
- The "Topics" are represented as rectangles inside each "View".
- The "Header" and the "Topics" are nested within a main "ScrollView" container.

Please note that this is a simplified ASCII representation and may not accurately reflect the actual styling and layout of the React Native components. The purpose is to give a general idea of the nested structure causing performance issues.

The primary issue is that the current setup with nested `Views` and a header is causing performance problems, particularly when there are many topics within the `Views`.

To improve performance, I'm planning to replace the nested `Views` with `FlatList` components. The goal is to have two `FlatList` components positioned next to each other horizontally. When I scroll one `FlatList`, the other one should also scroll simultaneously, creating a synchronized scrolling effect (Important Note: it's essential to consider that FlatList items may have varying heights, which can result in layout discrepancies. Careful handling of dynamic item heights will be necessary to ensure a smooth user experience.)

I want the header to be treated as an element within the `FlatLists` and scrolled along with the content (which works if I'm using the non-optimal method).

The current structure using nested `Views` within `ScrollView` is as follows (simplified):

```
<ScrollView>
  <View>
    {/* General header content */}
  </View>
  <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      {/* Topics for the first column */}
    </View>
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      {/* Topics for the second column */}
    </View>
  </View>
</ScrollView>
```

To address the performance issues and implement synchronized scrolling, I want to update the above structure to use `FlatList` components instead. Additionally, I want to ensure that the header is treated as an element within the `FlatLists` and scrolls along with the content.

I would greatly appreciate any guidance, code examples, or relevant resources that can help me achieve this improved performance and synchronized scrolling behavior.

Thank you in advance for your help!